# difference between json string and parsed json string

Tags: json, parsing

what is the difference between json string and parsed json string?
for eg in javascript suppose i have a string in the json format say [{},{}]

parsing this string will also produce the same thing.

So why do we need to parse?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's just serialization/deserialization.

In Javscript code you normally work with the object, as that lets you easily get its properties, etc, while a JSON string doesn't do you much good.

```
var jsonobj = { "arr": [ 5, 2 ], "str": "foo" };
console.log(jsonobj.arr[1] + jsonobj.str);
// 2foo

var jsonstr = JSON.stringify(jsonobj);
// cannot do much with this
```

To send it to the server via an Ajax call, though, you need to serialize (stringify) it first.  Likewise, you need to deserialize (parse) from a string into an object when receiving JSON back from the server.

Answer (score 5):

Great question. The difference is transfer format.

JSON is only the 'Notation' of a JavaScript Object, it is not actually the JavaScript 'object-literal' itself. So as the data is received in JSON, it is just a string to be interpreted, evaluated, parsed, in order to become an actual JavaScript 'Object-Literal.

There is one physical difference between the two, and that is quotation marks. It makes sense, that JSON needs to be a string to be transferred. Here is how:

```
//A JavaScript Object-Literal

var anObj  = { member: 'value'}

//A JSON representation of that object

var aJSON = { "member":"value" }
```

Hope that helps. All the best! Nash

Answer (score 0):

I think a parsed json string should be the string data into the actual javascript objects and data arrays (or whichever language the json string contains)

Answer (score 0):

The JSON object contains methods for parsing JSON and converting values to JSON.

It can't be called or constructed, and aside from its two method properties it has no interesting functionality of its own.

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object object = parser.parse(Message.toString());
JSONObject arObj = (JSONObject) object;
```